# PHP Session without Cookies | Codeigniter

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, session, session-cookies

**Scenario**

I am working on a special kind of API that uses sms for call.

Here users send sms like 

`<APP NAME> <PARAMETERS>`
 to a gateway *say* 9888888888. Now the gateway server contacts the app's API (which in this case is my app) in this format
`http://myapi.com/myapp/api.php?mobileNo=912345678&userInput=<PARAMETERS>`

**Problem**

When the user is new I show him the welcome message and ask him options like 1> Register 2>Help 3>Something. Suppose he replies `1` or `2` or `3`. The gateway would send me a request like 
`http://myapi.com/myapp/api.php?mobileNo=912345678&userInput=1`
 Now that means the user wants to register but how would I tell the server so. It would be simple here by just coding register page to show up everytime `$_GET['userInput']==1` and so on for every number.
But the problem comes in when you use other parts of the app. Like if I am asking a user to reply 1 if he wants to do a certain job. How would, in this case, the server judge to register or to do that job ?

How would I judge what the user wants when I only have one parameter passed on to me. For example I have two pages, one where user replies with 1 where he wants to insert something and on the other page where the user replies with 1 when he wants to contact me.

Comment: no idea what your asking i am sorry

Comment: Can't you just connect the mobile number to a pseudo-cookie in your database to keep track of where the user is in the process?

Comment: @user1618143 Can you please describe or link an example where its implemented. This scenario is new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use database-based sessions to keep track of where the user is in the process. For example consider the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `mobile_session` (
`mobile_number` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
`stage` TINYINT(2) NOT NULL
);
```

Each possible group of inputs from the user is assigned an internal identifier, for example your registration page could be 1, the contact page 2, etc. Whenever a user contacts you, update the database with their mobile number and the group of inputs they are expecting back. For example if 1 is your registration page.

```
REPLACE INTO `mobile_session` VALUES ([[users phone number]], '1');
```

Then when you receive a request like this:

```
http://myapi.com/myapp/api.php?mobileNo=912345678&userInput=1
```

You can look up that phone number in the table to see what group of inputs that user is replying to, in this case you will know that the user is replying to the registration page.